# is there SEO value in redirecting http://example.org to http://www.example.org?

Tags: seo

For many websites, the "www" part of the URL is optional, e.g. http://mysite.com and http://www.mysite.com are often aliases for the same page.

According to [this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/27/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www.aspx), there's an SEO benefit to redirecting all requests to http://mysite.com to http://www.mysite.com.

Is this really true? It seems to me that Google should be smart enough to check whether http://www.mysite.com and http://mysite.com are pointing to the same page, and only treat them as distinct pages if the content at each URL is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems to me that Google should be smart enough to check whether http://www.mysite.com and http://mysite.com are pointing to the same page.

They're not. That's why they offer the option to set your [preferred domain in Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en).

> The preferred domain is the one that you would liked used to index your site's pages (sometimes this is referred to as the canonical domain). Links may point to your site using both the www and non-www versions of the URL (for instance, http://www.example.com and http://example.com). The preferred domain is the version that you want used for your site in the search results.
>
> Once you tell us your preferred domain name, we use that information for all future crawls of your site and indexing refreshes. For instance, if you specify your preferred domain as http://www.example.com and we find a link to your site that is formatted as http://example.com, we follow that link as http://www.example.com instead. In addition, we'll take your preference into account when displaying the URLs. If you don't specify a preferred domain, we may treat the www and non-www versions of the domain as separate references to separate pages.

Answer (score 1):

If it matters for search engine robots, it's because it matters for human beings.

[URL canonicalization](http://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization) and redirection help SEO, yes, by concentrating otherwise diluted link juice.

Canonicalization matters for a [variety of reasons](http://searchengineland.com/why-canonicalization-matters-from-a-linking-perspective-91227) -- mainly, because it organizes information, coherently associating diverse/disparate references to a single resource address.

For example, the following hypothetical URLs would likely all point to the same page (in this case, the home page of a site):

- [example.com](http://example.com)
- [www.example.com](http://example.com)
- [www.example.com/](http://example.com)
- [www.example.com/index.html](http://example.com)
- [www.example.com/index.html?var1=360](http://example.com)
- [www.example.com/index.html?var1=46&var2=glenn](http://example.com)
- https://example.com
- https://www.example.com
- https://www.example.com/
- https://www.example.com/index.html
- https://www.example.com/index.html?var1=420
- https://www.example.com/index.html?var1=46&var2=glenn
- http://example.com
- http://www.example.com
- http://www.example.com/
- http://www.example.com/index.html
- http://www.example.com/index.html?var1=420
- http://www.example.com/index.html?var1=46&var2=glenn

Which among the above is the best URL to serve as the canonical ultimate destination?

There is a correct answer (imho), but it's not listed above: https://example.com/

Why?

1. [Trailing Slash: dramatically improves page load time.](http://glennfriesen.com/improve-page-load-time-by-including-a-trailing-slash-on-urls/)
2. HTTPS: it's more secure than HTTP:
3. Non-www Root: I'm in [the non-www camp](http://no-www.org/) because I prefer fewer characters in URLs, but [there are good reasons for the WWW as well](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/www-vs-non-www-for-your-canonical-domain-url-which-is-best-and-why/) including cookie-restriction and more DNS flexibility. Whether to go with www.example.com or just example.com (or even art.example.com) depends on your taste, preference, age, needs, plans, and goals.